# WebSQL, MongoDB ou Sqlite3, vantagens/desvantagens de cada um ao ser usado com Phonegap?

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, mongodb, websql

Tendo em conta a utilização em Phonegap quais são as vantagens/desvantagens de cada um.

Comment: Não temos como saber qual é o melhor. Para cada situação um deles pode ser o melhor. Inclusive precisa analisar coisas muito subjetivas para decidir.